# How do you set the default file extension for a syntax in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

I'm not asking about associating a syntax with a file extension, but about associating a file extension with a syntax. That is, setting the file extension suggested in the save file dialog after you create a new file, then set the syntax, then hit save.

You can change the extension in the save dialog, but it would be better not to have to do that every time.

Comment: I don't think sublime text can do that. Even if there is a plugin to do that, it isnt guaranteed to work reliably. Its best to allow the user to choose the extension when saving the file (which seems to be the default in mac at least)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For saving plain text files with a `.txt` extension by default, you can achieve this with a small plugin:

```py
import sublime
import sublime_plugin


class DefaultPlainTextExtensionEventListener(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
    def update_default_extension(self, view, syntax):
        if syntax == 'Packages/Text/Plain text.tmLanguage':
            view.settings().set('default_extension', 'txt')
        elif view.settings().get('default_extension', None) == 'txt':
                view.settings().erase('default_extension')
    
    def on_new_async(self, view):
        self.update_default_extension(view, view.settings().get('syntax'))

    def on_post_text_command(self, view, command_name, args):
        if command_name == 'set_file_type':
            self.update_default_extension(view, args['syntax'])
        elif command_name in ('paste', 'paste_and_indent'):
            self.update_default_extension(view, view.settings().get('syntax'))
```

Note that we can't use the `on_pre_save` event because the file dialog has already been shown to the user by the point this is triggered, and the file name chosen.

The idea is that, when a new tab is created or the syntax is changed to Plain Text, it will set the `default_extension` setting to `txt`. If the syntax changes to something else, it will remove the `default_extension`.

---

For changing the default file extension for a syntax, it requires changing the `.sublime-syntax` file to [re-order the file extensions set](https://github.com/sublimehq/Packages/pull/652), so that the default one is first in the list.
(Using the `default_extension` referenced earlier [is unreliable](https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/1527).)

So, for Markdown, you could do the following to change the default from `.mdown` to `.md`:

1. Install [PackageResourceViewer](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageResourceViewer) if it is not already installed
2. Open the Command Palette
3. Type `PRV: O`
4. Select `PackageResourceViewer: Open Resource`
5. Select `Markdown`
6. Select `Markdown.sublime-syntax`
7. Find where it says:

   ```yaml
   file_extensions:
     - mdown
     - markdown
     - markdn
     - md
   ```
8. Change it so that `md` is at the top:

   ```yaml
   file_extensions:
     - md
     - mdown
     - markdown
     - markdn
   ```
9. Save the file

Then, when you create a new tab, set the syntax to Markdown and save it, it will default to the `.md` file extension.

Note that you could try to create an issue/PR at the relevant GitHub repo, if you believe that changing the default could benefit others too and want to see the repo maintainer's reaction.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've created a [a PR](https://github.com/sublimehq/Packages/pull/755) changing this, we'll see where it goes.

Comment: PR is merged! It's a shame we never found a robust way to handle this on a case-by-case basis, but maybe .md is the exception and it isn't generally necessary. So, accepting this answer.

Comment: @KeithHall Upvoted, but not completely understand. You write: "For saving plain text files with a .txt extension by default..." -- But couldn't we simply put `Plain text.sublime-settings` with `"default_extension": "txt"` inside it? In my tests, it works fine.

Comment: you know, I think that for some reason I never thought of that @johnc.j.- that seems like a much cleaner and easier solution! feel free to write your own answer and we can suggest that OP changes the accepted answer to yours :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you also trying to set, say, `.txt.` as the default file extension for when saving plaintext documents? I've looked around and as far as I've seen it's not currently possible to do so. Sadly the default `Plain Text` content type appears to be the only one that DOESN'T default to its specific `.txt` extension even though it exists in the **Save as type** dropdown in the **Save As** window:

[image: Plain Text documents have a filetype set, but Sublime never uses it]

I've seen the [AdvancedNewFile](https://github.com/skuroda/Sublime-AdvancedNewFile) plugin recommended as a way to work around this but I don't have any personal experience with it.

Comment: Yes, that's the idea. The one that I had in mind is defaulting to `.md` instead of `.mdown` when saving a new Markdown file.