# Sublime Text 3 - Default to Text File Type

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I am using SublimeText 3 and I would like new files to be created in plain text format (i.e. default to a .TXT extension when they are saved).

I followed the instructions in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9520540/sublime-text-2-default-document-type).

I created a new file called "default_file_type.sublime-settings" and placed it in the "Packages/User" directory. The file had the following content:

> { "default_new_file_syntax": "Packages/Text/Plain_text.tmLanguage",
>   "use_current_file_syntax": false }

I also unzipped the "Text.sublime-package" file, created a new directory called "Text", and renamed the "Packages/Text/Plain text.tmLanguage" file to "Packages/Text/Plain_text.tmLanguage"

When I open SublimeText, I get an error:

> Error loading syntax file "Packages/Text/Plain_text.tmLanguage": Unable to load Packages/Text/Plain_text.tmLanguage

When I save a new file, it does not save in .TXT format.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29737006/how-do-you-set-the-default-file-extension-for-a-syntax-in-sublime-text-3/41257562#41257562

Answer (score 1):

The solution you posted requires several workarounds, and `tmLanguage` is in the process of being phased out by `sublime-syntax`.

The following steps implement the new `sublime-syntax` standard & a simple `EventListener` that executes when new files are created.

---

Save the following code as `Packages/NewFileSyntax/TXT.sublime-syntax`:

```
%YAML 1.2
---
name: TXT
comment: TXT documents
file_extensions:
  - txt
scope: txt.source
contexts:
  main:
    - match: .*
      scope: text.plain
```

---

Save the following code as `Packages/NewFileSyntax/NewFileSyntax.py`:

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class NewFileSyntax( sublime_plugin.EventListener ):
  def on_new( self, view ):
    view.set_syntax_file( "Packages/NewFileSyntax/TXT.sublime-syntax" )
```

Comment: What should be the content of the "DefaultLanguage.py" file?      import sublime, sublime_plugin

class EverythingIsPowerShell(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
   def on_new(self, view):
      view.set_syntax_file('Packages/PowerShell/Support/PowershellSyntax.tmLanguage')

Comment: Thanks for your help. I believe I followed the instructions correctly & created two new files with the specified content. But when I create a new file and save it, it does not default to the .TXT extension. In fact, the .TXT extension is no longer an option in the Save As dialogue.

Comment: @mariita : Are both files located in the directory structure: `Packages/NewFileSyntax/` ? The `NewFileSyntax` folder must be an exact match without spaces, since that is how it's entered in the code.  I just tested the code from the answer to make sure there weren't any errors & it [**seems to work fine**](http://i.imgur.com/xODlK6w.png).  Are you able to access the `TXT` syntax via the syntax menu?

Comment: Yes, both files are in the directory structure `Packages/NewFileSyntax/` and I don't believe that I have inserted any extraneous spaces. I see a Plain Text option in the syntax menu, but not a TXT option.

Comment: Although I did create a folder called NewFileSyntax, I'm wondering if I missed the step of explicitly creating a new package.

Comment: I'm wondering if my previous attempts to set the default filetype have somehow corrupted the installation. I will uninstall and reinstall SublimeText and then try the above once more.

Comment: I uninstalled SublimeText 3 and reinstalled the latest version (build 3103) and then followed the instructions above. Now I'm getting the error message: `Error loading syntax file "Packages/Powershell/Support/PowershellSyntax.tmLanguage": Unable to open Packages/Powershell/Support/PowershellSyntax.tmLanguage`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111313/discussion-between-enteleform-and-mariita).

Comment: I did post a response in chat. Apologies for the delay but I've never used the chat function before.